# GridView Layout text fill issue and empty cells

Tags: android, android-layout, android-gridview

I have a GridView and the text cells fills always vertically,
in addition for some strange reason the attribute Refer, that could be RDA or AI, is showed only if is RDA, AI seems invisible (my table in the column *Refer* hasn't empty cells).

See this screenshot for better understanding
[image]

the GridView is populated with this method

```
private void populateGrid(){
    Cursor c = dba.getNutriData():
    startManagingCursor(c);

    String[] from = new String[] { dba.Nutrient, dba.Intake, dba.Limit, dba.Refer};
    int[]   to = new int[] { R.id.txtNutrient, R.id.txtIntake, R.id.txtLimit, R.id.txtRefer};

    SimpleCursorAdapter sca = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.grid_row, c, from, to);

    grid.setAdapter(sca);
}
```

I use this GridView Layout

```
       <GridView
            android:id="@+id/tabellaDieta"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
            android:gravity="start"
            android:numColumns="1"
            android:scrollingCache="true"
            android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
            android:textAlignment="textStart" >

        </GridView>
```

And this is the gridrow layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<TableLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  >
  <TableRow android:layout_gravity="left">

  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/colNome"
      android:layout_width="50px"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_gravity="left"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      android:gravity="left|start"
      android:padding="5px"
      android:textColor="@color/white"
      android:textSize="12dp" />

  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/colDose"
      android:layout_width="50px"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_gravity="left"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      android:gravity="left|start"
      android:padding="5px"
      android:textColor="@color/greenlight"
      android:textSize="12dp" >

</TextView>

  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/colLimite"
      android:layout_width="50px"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_gravity="left"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      android:gravity="left|start"
      android:padding="5px"
      android:textColor="@color/orange"
      android:textSize="12dp" />

  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/colRiferimento"
      android:layout_width="50px"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_gravity="left"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      android:gravity="left|start"
      android:padding="5px"
      android:textColor="@color/light_sky"
      android:textSize="12dp" >

</TextView>

  </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The value of  this  `android:layout_weight="1"` and this line `android:padding="5px"` and this line `android:numColumns="1"` are critical.

test it by removing the `weight` and `padding` line and increase the number of `columns`

also you have fixed the width of `textView` here `android:layout_width="50px"` make it to `WrapContent`